# How can I change the default Nautilus Bookmarks?

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

So when I add a new user, I want them to have a nice set of Nautilus bookmarks pre-loaded.

If I look in:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

I see this:

```
...
file:///home/myuserid/Documents
file:///home/myuserid/Music
file:///home/myuserid/Pictures
file:///home/myuserid/Videos
file:///home/myuserid/Downloads
...
```

Simple enough but actually not very helpful. How does this file get created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your own bookmarks file. On each line, specify a bookmark URL (either as `file:///...` or `smb://` or `ftp://`, etc) followed by a space and a user-friendly name, which may contain spaces. Nautilus will pick it up automatically.

Comment: Probably, but wouldn't that usually involve some kind of scripting? The `useradd` command doesn't create the bookmark file; the above bookmarks are created at installation time. I merely explained how such a file could be created on the fly for a new user.

Comment: What I think happens is that nautilus copies it from somewhere or creates it the first time you launch it. Easy test. Move the file, and launch.

Comment: Test results: Moving the file did not result in the creation of a new file on re-launch. Hm...

Comment: I can put the file/directory structure in /etc/skel and that works except because they used file:// urls and don't appear to support Unix standards (for heaven's sake!) like environment variables and ~/, you are stuck with /home/the wrong user/ As far as I can tell the only way to fix is by scripting a sed command or something. :-/